# Dual flush toilet woes

Tags: repair, toilet

We've got an Ideal Standard Space corner toilet with a dual flush system. The flush button broke – it turns out as a result of the flush plate not being aligned with the button housing. In other words, the plastic screw had originally been forced into position and the bent rods eventually broke.

So, we're replacing the dual flush button.

We had to straighten up the cistern tank first as it wasn't level and the valve canister was just too out of whack. Now it's sitting much better.

We've also adjusted the valve canister height in order to properly fit the securing plastic screw. But the cistern now won't refill. The water is running but it seems to run straight out again. What is causing this?

However, when the flush button isn't screwed in place, all the mechanisms seem to be working fine (pushing down on the flush plate with a pencil – but we don't want to do that forever).

We are baffled as to why screwing in the flush button is messing up the whole system. Any ideas? We're a bit stuck and don't know what to do next. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push-rods between the buttons and the flush mechanism need to be adjusted because, as you've noticed, when you put everything together they're pushing on the flush mechanism and allowing water through - so they're a little too long.

You'll probably find that the end of the rods witch connect to the buttons is threaded, and there's some form of locking nut to hold them in place.
Loosen the nuts a few turns, screw the rods in a few turns to shorten them, re-tighten the nuts, and try again ...

Comment: Thank you, your solution was spot on. Yes, we shortened the rods, which made them fit better in the housing and released some of the pressure on the flush plate. But the real clincher was loosening the plastic screw. Sorted! Cheers and thanks, brhans.